# jQuery FOR statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I want to hide many elements. Do I need to hide each individually or can I use FOR?
If so, how to do it?

I've got this code:

```
   for (I=0; I <11; I++){
      $('div#r'+I).hide();
   }
```

But I don't know what exacly write inside FOR and this one is probably wrong written.

Comment: Just give all of them a class, then use the class selector to hide them.

Comment: i don't think the regex solutions are a good way to go, it's more difficult to code, read and maintain.  use classes and selectors, that's what they are there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can hide all the divs starting with a specific id with

```
 $('div[id^="r"]').hide();
```

but I would recommend giving them a class which makes it easier

```
 <div class="hidethis" id="r0">hidden</div>
 <div class="hidethis" id="r1">hidden</div>
 <div class="hidethis" id="r2">hidden</div>
```

then

```
  $(".hidethis").hide();
```

Answer (score 5):

to follow up on interstellar_coder's suggestion, you would do something like this

HTML:

```
<div class="hide-me" id="r0">this will be hidden</div>
<div class="hide-me" id="r1">this too</div>
<div class="hide-me" id="r2">this also</div>
```

Hide them all

JQUERY:

```
$("#hide-them").click(function() {
   $(".hide-me").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
// hide all divs with IDs starting with 'r'
$('div[id^="r"]').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: Dangerous! This is a rather big assumption.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder - true, but the risk can be mitigated by having more leading letters in the ID.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't wrong. Just delete `div` from your selector, which may make it even faster

```
  $('#r'+I).hide();
```

Or, if you want to hide a group of divs, just switch from id to class. In that case, it might look like

```
<div class="r">hide this</div>
<div class="r">hide this</div>
<div class="r">hide this</div>
<div class="r">hide this</div>
<script>
$('.r').hide();
</script>
```

which will hide them all

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to get all the elements that start with an r

```
$('div[id=^r]' ).hide()
```

Or if you only want ID's that start with an R and then have an integer

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    return $(this).attr("id").match(/r[\d]/);
}).hide();
```

Comment: Typo `id=^=r` needs to be `id^=r`. I fixed it, guess it got overwritten.

Comment: Thnx, yeah I've added a match where only R + number is legal, you prob changed it when I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

It probably makes a lot more sense to use somekind of `selector` to grab all the elements you want to hide and then just execute `.hide()` on the whole wrapped set.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the `for` loop, you can use `JQuery` selectors with `regex` to select `div`s starting with `r` followed by a digit and `hide()` them:

```
$('div:regex(id, ^r[0-9]+)').hide();
```

Comment: Please don't post code snippets as answers.  Explain how you arrived at this solution, and how it works.  For now, I've downvoted this.

Comment: @KevinVermeer I thought it's pretty self explanatory. You can always edit questions and answers if you think they're unclear. I'm not sure what exactly should be added; wrote a short explanation just in case.

Answer (score 1):

To loop through you need `.each` and to hide use `.hide`

Answer (score 1):

Applying a shared class would work, but you could just do a contains search on the id:

```
$("div[id^='r']").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

if each element has a common class it would be easier to hide them in one line; rather than having to iterate over each Id.

```
$('.divToHide').hide();
```